# Set focus to window based on ID using win32com.client's AppActivate

Tags: python, win32com

I've tried the following, but focus isn't returned to the program that had focus when the script was run:

```
import win32com.client
import win32gui

current = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")

shell.AppActivate('Console2')

shell.SendKeys('{UP}{ENTER}')

shell.AppActivate(str(current))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()` returns the window handle and not the process ID.

`win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)` can be used to get the thread ID and process ID from the handle.

```
import win32com.client
import win32gui
import win32process

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()

_, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")

shell.AppActivate('Console2')
shell.SendKeys('{UP}{ENTER}')

shell.AppActivate(pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Not enough rep to comment this*

In addition to Acorn's answer (so long ago), you should now be able to use SetFocus(handle).

```
import win32com.client
import win32gui

hwnd = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")

shell.AppActivate('Console2')
shell.SendKeys('{UP}{ENTER}')

win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
```

Source: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__SetFocus_meth.html