# Why isn't my mouse event registering inside window?

Tags: python, winapi

Fairly new to Python here, kind of just fooling around with it trying to learn the basics, this is my simple little program here so far, all it does is click the mouse when the Z key is pressed:

```
import win32gui, win32api, win32con, time

def clickMouse():
    print('Clicking Mouse')
    flags, hcursor, (mousex,mousey) = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,mousex,mousey,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,mousex,mousey,0,0)

while 1:
    print('Looping')
    if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(ordz('Z')):
        clickMouse()

    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Everything works great and the mouse event is being recognized e.g. it will highlight the text in here if I hold Z with my mouse in this textfield, but when I try to do it inside of a program or something it doesn't seem to register the mouse event.

Any idea on why this might be? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095266/set-focus-to-window-based-on-id-using-win32com-clients-appactivate

Comment: This wrong stacked on top of wrong. If you absolutely must fake input, don't use [mouse_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260.aspx). Use [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) instead. The real solution generally is: Do not fake input at all. It will break. Use the standard, supported interface for UI automation. It goes by the name [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).